# How to resize the UITabBarItem?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, swift

My code here:

```
for (NSInteger i = 1; i<= 4 ; i ++) {

    UIViewController *VC = self.viewControllers[i-1];
    UIImage *itemImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:[self getTabBarItemImageNameFromIndex:i selected:NO]] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAutomatic];

    UIImage *itemImageSelected = [[UIImage imageNamed:[self getTabBarItemImageNameFromIndex:i selected:YES]]imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAutomatic];

    UITabBarItem *item = [[UITabBarItem alloc]initWithTitle:[self getTabBarItemTitleWithIndex:i] image:itemImage selectedImage:itemImageSelected];

    item.tag = i-1;
    VC.tabBarItem = item;
}
```

First I run :
[image]

I want to shrink the UITabBarItem size, the original size of picture is 36 × 36 pixels.

Then I add these code:

```
       item.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(3, 3, 3, 3);
```

[image]

It does well,but when I press the TabBarItem the size of item was changed
[image]

I know the issue is about the setting of imageInsets, but I don't know how to resize the TabBarItem without to set imageInsets.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the standard UITabBar control is very customizable. I would recommend you create your own custom tab bar which fits your need, or use something like [UISegmentedControl](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/Reference/UISegmentedControl.html) which is quite customizable.

Have a look at these threads for reference:

[how to resize iphone tab bar in xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15459161/how-to-resize-iphone-tab-bar-in-xcode)

[How do I resize the tab bar items in Xcode 4.3.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10762036/how-do-i-resize-the-tab-bar-items-in-xcode-4-3-1)